# why does /var/mail/{username} = /Users/{username}?

Tags: alias, cd-command

My basic question is why do both of these paths point to home (i.e., `~`)? Is it pointing to the same home or is it duplicated?

I doubt it's duplicated, so if not, how does `cd ..` decide which directory to take me back to?

Comment: it does not for me. Your distro probably provides symlink. Read about [symlinks on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Answer (score 0):

How `cd ..` behaves will depend on the shell, the shell settings, and 
whether (as is likely in this case) symlinks are involved.

```
bash-4.1$ cd /var/tmp
bash-4.1$ mkdir -p real/cats
bash-4.1$ ln -s real/cats dogs
bash-4.1$ cd dogs/
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/tmp/dogs
bash-4.1$ pwd -P
/var/tmp/real/cats
bash-4.1$ cd ..
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/tmp
bash-4.1$ set -o physical
bash-4.1$ cd dogs
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/tmp/real/cats
bash-4.1$ cd ..
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/tmp/real
bash-4.1$
```

Investigating the `/var/mail` directory with `ls` should reveal if there are any symlinks done by I'm guessing Apple.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS (which I'm guessing this is since you mention `/Users`), the `/var/mail/username` is the `mbox`-formatted inbox mailbox for user `username`, and `/Users/username` is the home directory for the same user.

On an ordinary, non-modified installation of macOS, `/var/mail/username` will *not* be a symbolic link to the user's home directory, nor will `/Users/username` be a link to `/var/mail/username`.

---

`cd ..` will by default work like `cd -L ..`, i.e. it will take you up to the *logical* parent directory rather than the *physical* parent directory (`cd -P ..`).

From the `ksh`-manual on macOS:

> By default, symbolic link names are treated literally when finding the directory name.  This  is
>                 equivalent  to the `-L` option.  The `-P` option causes symbolic links to be resolved when determining the directory.  The last instance of `-L` or `-P` on the command line determines which method is
>                 used.